# Creating a table programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-table

I have been searching for quite some time to create the following table through code-behind using C#. I am finding difficulty in adding a `<tr>` to `<thead>` and `<tr>` to `<tbody>`. This is how the table should look like:

```
<table id="mytable" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" >
     <caption>myCaption</caption>
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <th scope="col">myHeader1</th>
             <th scope="col">myHeader2</th>
             <th scope="col">myHeader3</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>1</td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Dave, it is MVC...

Comment: and how's your model looks like?

Comment: @RVP FYI check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704802/making-html-tables-in-mvc4-using-strongly-typed-models

Answer (score 2):

Create a strongly typed view with a list of whatever you're binding, and use the `@foreach` loop:

```
@model List<MyClass>

<table id="mytable" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" >
 <caption>myCaption</caption>
 <thead>
     <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <th scope="col">myHeader1</th>
         <th scope="col">myHeader2</th>
         <th scope="col">myHeader3</th>
     </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    @foreach(var m in Model)
    {
     <tr>
         <td>@m.MyProp1</td>
         <td>@m.MyProp2</td>
         <td>@m.MyProp3</td>
     </tr>
    }
 </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar thing using C# MVC. Here is a sample code. Hope this will help to get an idea.

```
@{int count = Model.HeadingsList.Count;}
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (string heading in Model.HeadingsList)
            {
                <th>@heading</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (string row in Model.rowsList)
        {
            string[] cellValues = Array.ConvertAll(row.Split(','), p => p.Trim());
            if (count != cellValues.Count()) { return; } 
            <tr>
                @for (int i = 0; i < @count; i++) 
                {
                            <td>@cellValues[i]</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I had a list of rows like below.
Array[0]['cell1','cell2','cell3'...]
Array[1]['cell1','cell2','cell3'...]